# Middleware and Compojure destructuring syntax

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have the following Compojure routes:

```
(defroutes my-handler
  (GET "/:my-model-id" [id] (render-my-model (parse-int id))))
```

It is unfortunate that, for every route that I define this way, I have to manually add a call to parse the incoming integer.

I have created Ring middleware that crawls through any `form-params` and `request-params`, and parses anything that looks like it might be an integer.  However, this middleware does not apply to the custom-defined Compojure routes.

Does anybody know how I could get Compojure to automatically handle the integer-parsing?  Can I somehow hook it up to my existing middleware?

Comment: Could you provide the middleware code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `compojure` will directly invoke the function that is generated from your route definition after it has parsed the params.

AFAIC the only way to get in between is either to modify compojures codebase directly or to use Robert Hooke (by technomancy) on `assoc-route-params` in https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/master/src/compojure/core.clj#L30

Comment: Thanks.  I just realized that there is a route-params field; I'll experiment with writing some custom middleware to alter it.

Comment: The point is just that you can't get between Compojures parser and your handler unless you use a function like `make-route` allowing you to provide a handler /function/. Then you could `comp` your middleware on top of it e. g. in a loop. This wouldn't allow you to use Compojures destructoring magic though. If I am not wrong with my assertion I think it's a feature the library is clearly missing, given that you can e. g. instruct it to only parse decimals (by using a vector with a regex for the route-string), it should offer convenient ways for typecasting.